# How to simulate vertical core location or altitude in Xcode for IPS (Indoor Positioning)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The iOS [Core Location API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation) can provide data about the device's vertical position via estimates of altitude from a number of sources. Many venues (including many major public buildings) have Indoor Positioning Systems (IPS) certified by Apple's [Indoor Maps Program](https://register.apple.com/indoor) whereby location-specific infrastructure such as Wi-Fi access points or beacons plus topographic data verified by an approved survey can be used to accurately indicate a user's vertical position within a multistorey building.

XCode and the iOS Simulator have tools for simulating the device's (horizontal) latitude and longitude, but I can't find a way to simulate vertical position.

Is there any way to configure Xcode and/or the iOS simulator to make a connected real or simulated device behave as if it is on a certain altitude, floor or vertical position?

For example, I can set device latitude and longitude to behave as if it is in a particular building in a public IPS location like a hospital or airport, and apps like Apple Maps that use Core Location will show the user as being on a default floor (usually the ground floor). Is there any way I can configure the simulator or device such that apps using Core Location will treat the user as being on a different floor?